# Hide-Unhide Filter Control Button in Group Box

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a dynamic range excel 2016 sheet where the header row is 3, data range starts at 4 and is ever expanding.

- Column A contains names of Students
- Column J contains a drop down list:  "Excellent, Very Good, Good, Average, Poor" the option is selected based on term results.

I would like to have control Box "All, Excellent, Very Good, Good, Average, Poor"

when criteria in control box is selected only those rows satisfying should be displayed. when "All" is selected all rows should be displayed.

Can anyone help me with the macros/VBA code for Control Button (ActiveX) in Group Box.

Alternatively can we use ActiveX tick box(Form Control) in Group Box for the same.

Comment: why not just use autofilter? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Quick-start-Filter-data-by-using-an-AutoFilter-08647E19-11D1-42F6-B376-27B932E186E0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are over-complicating a rather simple task.

Select your data, then, On the Data tab, in the Sort & Filter group, click Filter.  This is called an auto-filter, one of Excel's most widely used features.

You will see all the values in each column, with check-boxes to select and view the ones you want.